# How to change columns to rows and get the values of important KPIs in pyspark or python

Tags: python, pyspark

```
month   Region    Division  Revenue account
May     LA          West      50      20
May     California  East      80      30
May     Georgia     North     40      20
April   LA          West      60      25
```

The above is the input table

I need the output table in the below way

```
Month   Region     Division     KPI      value
May       LA         West      Revenue     20
May    California    East      Revenue     80
May     Georgia      North     Revenue     40
May       LA         West      Account     20
May     California   East      Account     30
May      Georgia     North     Account     20
April      LA        West      Revenue     60
April      LA        West      Account     25
```

Can anyone help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need was to `unpivot` in `pyspark` you can use `stack` function to achieve `unpivoting` like below

```
# create data frame
df = spark.createDataFrame(
[
("May","LA","West",50,20),
("May","California","East",80,30),
("May","Georgia","North",40,20),
("April","LA","West",60,25)], 
("month", "Region", "Division", "Revenue", "account"))

# use stack function 
df1 = df.selectExpr("month","Region", "Division","stack(2, 'Revenue', Revenue, 'account', account) as (KPI, value)")
```

Comment: Can we also do count of a column in the same.. if there is an column with indicator 1,0 in the input dataset so can we have a KPI for count of those?

Comment: @ShivanandaSahoo Yes you can do that